# Calling JavaScript function in If-Else Statement

Tags: javascript, vb.net

VB.Net:

```
Protected Sub btnFinish_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFinish.Click

            For a As Integer = 0 To grdQ.Rows.Count - 1 Step a + 1
                Dim an As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.grdQ.Rows(a).FindControl("txtAnswer"), TextBox)
                If an.Text = String.Empty Then
                    'do something
                    Exit For
                ElseIf an.Text <> "" Then
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Me.GetType(), "Script", "finAns();", True)
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
```

..JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function finAns() {
    $("#timeLeft").dialog({
                title: "There's Still Time Left!",
                open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                                          },
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false 
    });
       return false;
  }
</script>
```

What's wrong with these codes? It seems like it's not working. Calling the javascript function is not working.. I'm not so good with javascript that's why I need some help. Thanks :D

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Nothing. It just not fire the calling of JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","finAns()",true)
```